# Use JS function from external JS file

Tags: javascript, alpine.js, parcel

Using AlpineJS I have the folowing HTML and JS:

```
<form x-data="inquiry()" x-on:submit.prevent="submit" method="post">
</form>

<script>
  function inquiry() {

    return {

      data: { name: "" },

      submit() {
        // Do something
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

I moved the JS `inquiry` function to a JS file and used Parcel for building.

So the index.js file used as an entry point for Parcel is:

```
import './index.less'  

import inquiry from './inquiry.js' 

import alpine from 'alpinejs';

window.alpine = alpine;
alpine.start();

console.log("Hello");
```

I am importing the bundle in my HTML page using:

```
<script src="~/index.js" type="text/javascript" defer></script>
```

When I run my code and try to access `inquiry` function I get the error:

```
Alpine Expression Error: Can't find variable: inquiry
```

However I can see "Hello" in the console as result of `console.log("Hello")`

What am I missing?

Comment: How are you loading your scripts, could you perhaps show med the script-tags?

Comment: Maybe you forget to import this bundle in html.

Comment: @Fralle I am using `<script src="~/index.js" type="text/javascript" defer></script>
`

Comment: @bbbbbbbboat No I am not. I just added `console.log("Hello")` in my index.js file and it shows in the console when I run the application.

Comment: Fine. How about the source code where the error is throwed? It looks like it is calling a `global variable` which is declared by `var` or registered in `window`. But now you are importing it into the capsule of `index.js` module. I'm not familar with `alphine`, I hope I can help you a little.

Comment: @bbbbbbbboat The error is throned when I submit the form. It can't find inquiry() function and the submit method.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use modules. Could you set this attribute on the script tag?

```
<script src="~/index.js" type="module" defer></script>
```

Also ensure that you are correctly exporting inquiry from that file.